# How to call validateFields of namePath of Arrayed object

Tags: antd

When I print `form.getFieldsValue()`

I get this form object:

```
{ books: 
  {
    0: 
      {
        title: "hello"
        description: "this is a description"
      }
    1: 
      {
        title: "hello 2"
        description: "this is a description 2"
      }
  }
}
```

Within the form, I have functions that append new books to the form object.

```
{ books: 
  {
    0: {...}
    1: {...}
    2: {...}
    3: {...}
    4: {...}
     .
     .
     . 
  }
}
```

How do I call validate fields on all title fields which are required.

I tried various ways but am unable to validate all title fields in the form.

```
form.validateFields([ "books", "title" ]);
form.validateFields([ "books", "*", "title" ]);
form.validateFields([ "books", [], "title" ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form.validateFields([ "books", 0, "title" ]);
form.validateFields([ "books", 1, "title" ]);
form.validateFields([ "books", 2, "title" ]);
form.validateFields([ "books", 3, "title" ]);
```